# What does "soon to come " means?

Tags: phrases

What does **"soon to come"** mean, and when can we use it? Does the question

> Our day together on January 1st is *soon to come*.

mean that it is approaching soon?

Comment: Abby, I assume you understand "soon", and it looks like you understand "to come" (if not, google *define "to come"*). So where's the confusion? Please only ask questions here where you can't work out what the solution is, or you know what it is but you don't understand why it's correct (and you can show us the research you've done on it).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the phrase "soon to come" is used to say that something/somebody is **coming, getting closer, approaching**. Thus, we can rephrase the given sentence like this:

> We'll soon spend a day together (and that day is January 1st).

Here are more sentences to show how the phrase can be used:

> As a matter of fact, **she is soon to come to court**.
>
> The Mexican side briefed on the **soon-to-come Cancun summit** of the countries of Latin America and the Caribbean Basin.
>
> We also welcome the propitious initiative of Bethlehem 2000, the realization of which is **soon to come about**.

Answer (score 1):

**soon to come**

**soon**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/184685?rskey=cyahdD&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> Within a short time (after a particular point of time specified or
>   implied), before long, quickly

As in:  *Medieval Italy - an Enclycopedia*

> ... but although such appeals were not immediately successful, they
>   became the precedent for a momentous alliance **soon to come** between
>   the papacy and the Franks.  [google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=E2CTAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT487&dq=%22soon%20to%20come%22%20dictionary&pg=PT487#v=onepage&q=%22soon%20to%20come%22%20dictionary&f=false)

and

1989   Record Mirror

> Their **soon to come** debut single..could well be a New Year monster.